# Find position vector of a parallelogram and a angle.

Tags: vectors

ABCD is a parallelogram. Given three position vector, $A=2i+j+3k$, $B=3i-2j$, $C=i-j-2k$. Find position vector of D and calculate angle of ABC.

any help with this question?

Answer (score 0):

First we should calculate vector $\vec{BA}$ and $\vec{BC}$

The angle of ABC could be calculated by inner product

$$cos\theta=\frac{\vec{BA} \cdot \vec{BC}}{|\vec{BA}||\vec{BC}|}$$

Furthermore, because of the parallelogram, $ \vec{CD}= \vec{BA} $.

That's all